# How to improve speed of csv upload to cassandra

Tags: csv, cassandra

I created a table in cassandra with this command:

```
create table deltas (
tag text,
date text,
time text,
value double, 
primary key 
((tag,date),time));
```

Then I imported a csv file with this command:

```
copy deltas from 'blast.csv' with delimiter=',';
```

Here is a little sampling of the csv file:

```
10000001,2017-02-17,17:05:18.1620000,2
10000001,2017-02-17,17:06:18.1510000,3
10000001,2017-02-17,17:26:25.4160000,1
10000001,2017-02-17,17:32:18.3960000,5
```

On a single core machine, about 5000 rows are copied per second. I really expected on the order of a million rows per second on a single core. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Which cqlsh version are you using ?

Comment: By the way you don't need to specify ',' as delimiter, because it's default

Comment: Copy isn't designed as a fast bulk loading tool. You'll either want to use Spark, SSTable loader, or write your own Java app. Also, achieving a million writes per second on a single core, single machine is a little out there.

Comment: @Ashraful I'm using `[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.10 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]`. @Marc, I'll try Spark and SSTable loader. I'm also considering kafka.

Comment: @GregClinton you can tune the parameter `NUMPROCESSES`, `INGESTRATE`, `CHUNKSIZE` etc More http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/tools/cqlsh.html?highlight=cqlsh#copy-from